# `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError) Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

I'm new to ruby, I cloned a repo and ran `bundle install`, but when I run my app got the following error:

```
  1: from /Users/sachendra/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/Users/sachendra/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError)
        72: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        71: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        70: from /Users/sachendra/Desktop/data_service/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        69: from /Users/sachendra/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
        68: from /Users/sachendra/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
        67: from /Users/sachendra/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
         1: from /Users/sachendra/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/Users/sachendra/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': dlopen(/Users/sachendra/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace '_ffi_prep_closure' - /Users/sachendra/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
```

I found people with same issues but none of them have problem in rails and any of them is useful for me.
I'm using mac-os.